# Book (or trilogy) set in 1950s UK where the protagonist has a sandwich shop

Tags: story-identification, books

The things I can remember are:

1. British author and set, mainly in the UK
2. The main character (an ordinary bloke) is gifted a sandwich shop that I *think* is called "Sam Widges".
3. The plot has similarities to The Illuminatus Trilogy.
4. I'm fairly sure it too was a trilogy.
5. It starts in the late 1950s/early 1960s

This is driving me crazy and any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Could you be thinking of The Warp Trilogy by Neil Oram? Here is a link and if you do a "find on page" search you will get a lot of hits on Sam Widges.  http://www.cix.co.uk/~shutters/warpinterview.htm  Here is a wiki link that discusses it.  It was a "mega-play" that was put into book form but appears to be out of print and very obscure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Oram#mediaviewer/File:The_Warp_ICA_1979.jpg

Comment: "Widges" does indeed seem to be the name of a restaurant based on the link provided.